# Working with Parse and trying to parse a database entry in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

Here's a snippet of my code:

```
    // Other stuff to prime userQuery

    userQuery.first().then(function(posts) {    
       console.log(posts);  // to verify that I'm reading it
       var foo = posts.get("timeStamp");
       console.log(foo); } );
```

When I get the log back from Parse, I get a message:

```
I2014-12-11T23:03:09.213Z] {"ACL":{"T...","timeStamp":"2014-12-11T18:55:15.114Z","..."}
I2014-12-11T23:03:09.214Z] No Message provided
```

console.log(posts) is working.
console.log(foo) isn't.

I'm new at this and am probably missing something simple.

Comment: When you say `console.log(posts)` is working, what is it showing?

Comment: It's showing the I2014-12-11T23:03:09.213Z timestamped line.

Answer (score 0):

When you are using Cloud Code feature you **can't** use `console.log` directly. If you want to print that object use this - `console.log(JSON.stringify(DESIRED_OBJECT));`

So your code `console.log(posts);` will print kind of - `[Object object]` If you have stored that `timeStamp` field as DATE then you have to print like this - `console.log(new Date(foo));` Then it will time.